# sql like statement not working with JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I'm having a JSON field like this.

```
{"address": "nicholas street, lidcombe, nsw 2141", "display": "Nicholas Street, LIDCOMBE, NSW 2141"}
```

I want to retrieve addresses which starts from first letter.Example if user type 'N' all the addresses which starts from N should be retrieved.  I'm having sql statement like this

```
    SELECT    addresses
FROM      Addresses
WHERE     JSON_EXTRACT(addresses, '$.display') LIKE "N%"
```

But I'm getting a null value.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT addresses
FROM Addresses
WHERE addresses REGEXP '"address":"N.*","display":".*"' ;
```

Comment: This query should be working.  There may be a problem with your data.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NULL data because JSON_EXTRACT returns `" Nicholas Street, LIDCOMBE, NSW 2141"`means the text starts with **double quote** and **space** thus `LIKE "N%"` does not work. So final query is:

```
SELECT    addresses
FROM      Addresses
WHERE     JSON_EXTRACT(addresses, '$.display') LIKE "\" N%"
```

Test here: http://rextester.com/YVS22096

**Note:** Modify your **LIKE** clause. I simply mentioned why you are getting NULL output

Comment: Not only for this example ,I'm getting null for others as well. I need the answer for that

Comment: I think you didn't get the problem that I mentioned. For the specific data you provided I mentioned that the selected data starts with double quote and space thus LIKE "N%" can not match value.

If you still do not understand what I meant, then provide more data.

Comment: How to use '?'  mark for above statement if I need to get value from user?

Comment: If you want to use ? as search pattern then simply add it. Please provide sample data and let me know what you want to do.